# Hotelling's T^2 and Q statistics for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, pca

so I've been working on PCA in matlab for anomaly detection in the dataset.
I have carried out the dimensionality reduction and the anomaly detection using the T^2 and Q statistics.
However I've noticed that when a true anomaly does occur in my code, the faulty data is being used to update the model. I've tried to stop it but to no avail.
Here's my code:

```
for i =5:(size(Qlimit))
    if Q(i) > Qlimit(i) && Q(i-1) > Qlimit(i-1) && Q(i-2) > Qlimit(i-2) && Q(i-3) > Qlimit(i-3) && Q(i-4) > Qlimit(i-4)
        for j = i:(i+Xwindow)
             Qlimit(j) = Qlimit(j-1);
             T2limit(j) = T2limit(j-1);        
        end
    end
end
```

So what I want to happen is if the Q value is greater than it's control limit I want to use the previous value for a certain number of times (Xwindow in the code), but when I do this if it happens near the end it looks for a value that doesn't exist.
I have only looked for times when the Q statistic is violated because the T^2 only violates for a few samples and doesn't last long but if I get it working for Q it's easy to implement for T^2.

Any Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Firstly

```
if Q(i) > Qlimit(i) && Q(i-1) > Qlimit(i-1) && Q(i-2) > Qlimit(i-2) && Q(i-3) > Qlimit(i-3) && Q(i-4) > Qlimit(i-4)
```

can be written as

```
if all(Q(i-4:i) > Qlimit(i-4:i))
```

If you are worried about edge cases then maybe you can try:

```
if all(Q(max(0,i-4):i) > Qlimit(max(0,i-4):i))
```

I don;t see what your question has to do with PCA though and I think you should change the title.

Comment: After using PCA to reduce the dimensionality of the dataset, I then use Hotelling's T^2 and Q statistics for monitoring of the system.

Comment: @MRaff16 then your question is about "Hotelling's T^2 and Q statistics" and not about PCA which you have already successfully implemented. So again, I think you should change the title.

Comment: is that better for you?

Comment: @MRaff16 yes that is a better title

Comment: can you offer any helping with stopping the updating of control limits?

Comment: Try `for j = i:min((i+Xwindow),numel(Q))`. This way `j` can never overflow `Q`

Comment: That seems to change all the data points to the previous value (and therefore all the same). I'm only looking to change the value when Q is over Qlimit